# How to write unit test cases or mock for this type of method or is my custom method removeUsers not good enough for unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, java-8, mockito

I am totally new to java 8 and unit tests. I am confused how do we write unit test cases scenario for this method RemoveUsers().
This is my class

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class LdapService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final MessageResolver messageResolver;

    @Autowired
    public LdapService(UserRepository userRepository, MessageResolver messageResolver) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.messageResolver = messageResolver;
    }

      public void removeUsers(List<PersonDTO> ldapUsers) {

    List<User> pmUsers = ldapUsers.stream()
            .filter(personDTO -> userRepository.getUserByUserId(personDTO.getUserId()).isPresent())
            .map(PersonDTO::getUserId)
            .map(userRepository::getUserByUserId)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> idsToBeDeleted = pmUsers.stream().map(User::get_id).collect(Collectors.toList());

    idsToBeDeleted.forEach(id -> {
        try {
            userRepository.deleteUser(id);
        } catch (DbApiException | RestApiException | IOException e) {
            log.error(messageResolver.message(MessageKeyEnum.ERROR_WHILE_DELETING_DATA));
        }
    });
}
```

}

I  tried to do below, but i am unable to figure it out how and I am sure the below unit test what i wrote needs modification. Could anyone help me out here?

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class Test {

```
@InjectMocks
private LdapService ldapService;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
void expectSuccesOnRemoveUsers() throws IOException {
    List<PersonDTO> personDTOList = Arrays.asList(
            PersonDTO.builder().dn("CN=abk_tch,OU=Users,OU=Bangalore,DC=apac,DC=dell,DC=com").userId("admin").build());
    String userId = "admin";
    UserUpdate userMock = UserUpdateMock.mockLdapUserWithDefaultValues().build();
    when(userRepository.getUserByUserId(userId)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userMock));
    ldapUserService.removeUsers(personDTOList);
    verify(userRepository,times(1)).deleteUser(userId);
}
```

}

Some object structure are mentioned below

getUserByUserId(id) returns Optional users

deleteUser(id) is void method receiving id

and personDto is as below

public class PersonDTO {

```
private String userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String dn;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Stream API is awful. The following code:

```java
    List<User> pmUsers = ldapUsers.stream()
            .filter(personDTO -> userRepository.getUserByUserId(personDTO.getUserId()).isPresent())
            .map(PersonDTO::getUserId)
            .map(userRepository::getUserByUserId)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> idsToBeDeleted = pmUsers.stream().map(User::get_id).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

could be replaced by:

```java
List<String> idsToBeDeleted = ldapUsers.stream()
        .map(PersonDTO::getUserId)
        .map(userRepository::getUserByUserId)
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .map(User::get_id)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, that won't help much, cause your case is actually demonstrating the situation when attempt to write unit test reveals broken API. Basically, method `#removeUsers` instead of being `void` must return information about which users have been deleted and which haven't and why, after refactoring `#removeUsers` you will able to pass there any input and check the output.

Comment: If i use the replacement that you provided, it says "cannot resolve method stream"

Comment: May be i can use below,                                                                                               List<String> idsToBeDeleted = ldapUsers.stream()
                .map(PersonDTO::getUserId)
                .map(userRepository::getUserByUserId)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .map(User::get_id)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: `Optional::stream` was introduced in Java 9, in case of Java 8 that would be `filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`

Comment: I was thinking if we can write unit test for my void method as as below. Please add your suggestion

Comment: void expectSuccessOnSyncLdapRemoveUsers() {
        List<PersonDTO> personDTOList = Arrays.asList(PersonDTO.builder().dn(null).userId("anyId").build());
        UserUpdate userMock = UserUpdateMock.mockLdapUserWithDefaultValues().build();
        when(userRepository.getUserByUserId(userMock.getUserId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(userMock));
        doNothing().when(userRepository).deleteUser(userMock.get_id());
        ldapUserService.syncLdapRemoveUsers(personDTOList);

Comment: verify(userRepository,times(1)).getUserByUserId(userMock.getUserId());
        verify(userRepository,times(1)).deleteUser(userMock.get_id());
    }